# Bootstrap grid not working?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I am loading in bootstrap grids to make my site responsive.. However, my div are not reacting to the tempaltes. The idea is that on a standard macbook or a larg screen the divs cover a 3rd of the page. And on mobile 100%. what is wrong with my code. Have i loaded in bootstrap?

```
 <html>
        <head>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/style.css">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        </head>
        <body>
            <div class="row">
                <div class"col-sm-12 col-lg-4 col-md-4" id="homeDiv1">
                </div>
                <div class"col-sm-12 col-lg-4 col-md-4" id="homeDiv2">
                </div>
                <div class"col-sm-12 col-lg-4 col-md-4" id="homeDiv3">
                </div>
            </div>
        </body>
        </html>
```

Answer (score 4):

Your classes need an equal sign.

Instead of

```
class"col-sm-12 col-lg-4 col-md-4"
```

You need

```
class="col-sm-12 col-lg-4 col-md-4"
```

Answer (score 2):

problem in `class"col-sm-12 col-lg-4 col-md-4"` use (**=**) like `class="col-sm-12 col-lg-4 col-md-4"`

```css
.row div{
    background-color:pink;
    border:1px solid gray;
    height:40px;
    }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/style.css">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-4 col-md-4" id="homeDiv1">
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-4 col-md-4" id="homeDiv2">
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-4 col-md-4" id="homeDiv3">
                </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Just a **typo**:

```
<div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-4 col-md-4" id="homeDiv1">
```

```css
.row > div
{
  height:100px;
  background:#ccc;
  padding:5px;
}
```

```html
<html>
        <head>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/style.css">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        </head>
        <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-4 col-md-4" id="homeDiv1">1
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-4 col-md-4" id="homeDiv2">2
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-4 col-md-4" id="homeDiv3">3
                </div>
            </div>
         </div>
        </body>
        </html>
```